# Pyqt/Python Use a variable from a script to another

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Let's name this MyScript:

I run the program and redirect me to a python script, but i want to use the data inserted in `lineedit` to the script that my programs opens and also when i run the program,when it redirects me to "MyScript1" i want the window from "MyScript "to close and run just the "MyScript1".

Comment: Could you explain me better

Comment: I have my main program above. I run it and a window opens with a line edit and a button. When i press the button it opens a script file named "MyScript1",but i want to press the button and opens "MyScript1" and use the variable that i wrote in the QLineEdit from Main Program. And also when "MyScript1" opens i want the main program to close and run just that script.

Comment: What you want is to run MyScript1 when you press a button and use the QLineEdit entry as a parameter for MyScript1, and at that point you want the initial window to close, am I correct? If so, I have a question as to how to use the QLineEdit parameter in MyScript1.

Comment: Yes. I have posted MyScript1 file to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a parameter to `MyScript1.py` you must use `sys.argv`. For this we add a third parameter to `process.call(...)`

```
def run(self,path):
    self.close()
    subprocess.call(['python',path, str(self.lineEdit.text())])
```

The script `MyScript1.py` receives it through `sys.argv[1]`. For that you must change:

```
person_name= raw_input('Care este numele persoanei pe care doresti sa o adaugi in baza de date?: ').lower()
```

to:

```
person_name= sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: When i press the button the window close. This work perfectly. I receive this error "TypeError: sequence item 16: expected string, QString found".I think when he tries to pass the line edit to "MyScript1".He doesn't pass the text i wrote.